# python array assignment by repitition

Tags: python, list

I am very confused while debugging my code.

```
a = [[0]*2]*3
a[2][1] = 2
print(a)
```

leads to and output of [[0, 2], [0, 2], [0, 2]]

while

```
b = [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]
b[2][1] = 2
print(b)
```

leads to and output of [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 2]]

What I intended was latter.
Why is the output as [[0, 2], [0, 2], [0, 2]] when using array repetition?

Comment: `[[0]*2]*3` creates a list with *three references to the same list*. i.e. `[x]*3` is equivalent to `[x, x, x]`.

Comment: `a = [[0]*2 for _ in range(3)]`.